# Custom trigger to execute failsafe in pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

The default trigger of failsafe pyautogui is drag mouse to up-left corner. if i do that then the program will stop. How to change trigger, instead drag mouse i want set the trigger with keyboard input. for example if i press P key then the program will stop (the failsafe executed)

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a way using pyautogui but it has been done using pynput. here is an example (pay attention to def keypress specifiaclly)

```
from random import random
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput.keyboard import KeyCode, Listener
import pyautogui

delay = float(pyautogui.confirm(text='Choose Clicking Speed Per Second', title='Spook AutoClicker', buttons=['0.5','0.001']))

mouse = Controller()


class AutoClicker(Thread):
    clicking = False

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if AutoClicker.clicking:
                mouse.click(Button.left)
            sleep(delay)


def keypress(key):
    if key == KeyCode(char="p"):
        AutoClicker.clicking = not AutoClicker.clicking


AutoClicker().start()

with Listener(on_press=keypress) as listener:
    listener.join()
```